# gSOAP to WCF . Application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8

Tags: c++, wcf, gsoap

I have simple web service running on `http://calculator.gear.host/Service1.svc`

I have no problem while do call from `WCF Test Client` and have error while calling from gSOAP c++ client.

```
HTTP/1.1 415 Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData"' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'.
```

Packets on `Fiddler`:

**WCF Test Client**

**Request**

```
 POST http://calculator.gear.host/Service1.svc HTTP/1.1
    Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
    SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/ICalculator/GetData"
    Host: calculator.gear.host
    Content-Length: 158
    Expect: 100-continue
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    Connection: Keep-Alive

    <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><GetData xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><value>77</value></GetData></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

**gSOAP**

**Request**

```
POST http://calculator.gear.host/Service1.svc HTTP/1.1
Host: calculator.gear.host
User-Agent: gSOAP/2.8
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData"
Content-Length: 536
Connection: close
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns4="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfService2" xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:GetData><ns1:value>55</ns1:value></ns1:GetData></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

**Answer**

```
HTTP/1.1 415 Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData"' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'.
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 0
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Set-Cookie: ARRAffinity=7ac8ab2e2023ddbeb7d4f86322b3ed25bc003394df0030ed244a6fc5c10ec47c;Path=/;Domain=calculator.gear.host
Set-Cookie: WAWebSiteSID=9095f7410a074a959c2084564368b742; Path=/; HttpOnly
Date: Tue, 28 Jul 2015 15:03:28 GMT
Connection: close
```

Answer (score 2):

I' have the same problem with a service not generated with gSOAP (probably using some tool in C#).
For your client gSOAP, recompile your WSDL file (soapcpp2.exe) using option -1 (generate SOAP 1.1 bindings).
This works for me.